# Order of insertion of array values at Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-dynamodb

When adding an array at DynamoDB with put_item, is there any way to tell it to preserve the order of the values of the array?

Example: I'm adding array("2", "1", "4"), and it's added to the table as 1, 2, 4. I don't want dynamo to mess up with my array :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as arrays in dynamoDB are Sets, they don't preserve any ordering.

best alternative for you is to concatenate them into a string (using a delimiter) and then inserting this string i.e. 2#1#4 and then split them when you read back.

Answer (score 2):

No. Although you use PHP arrays when inserting values, DynamoDB doesn't actually support arrays. Instead it offers sets, which don't have any ordering and don't allow duplicate values.